# How to prevent declaring an associative key while hardcoding array data?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Not sure if I can word this properly but I need to create and array with some array of other information. Right now it spits out like this:

[image]

And my code goes like this:

```
$calNames = array(
            'affordability',
            'balloon-payment',
            'budget',
            'early-payoff',
            'fuel-savings',
            'lease-vs-finance',
            'monthly-payment' => array( 'name' => 'test3' ),
            'refinance',
            'single-pay-lease',
        );

    print_r( $calNames );
```

I want it to create the array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => affordability
    [1] => monthly-payment
    [2] => budget
    [3] => early-payoff
    [4] => fuel-savings
    [5] => lease-vs-finance
    [6] => monthly-payment => Array
        (
            [name] => test3
        )

    [7] => refinance
    [8] => single-pay-lease
)
```

Comment: It's the same thing. `print_r` shows you the formatted indices. With your code, you can access $calNames[0] and it would be 'affordability'

Comment: `[6] => monthly-payment => Array(...)` doesn't make sense, since `monthly-payment` is an array. [6] is its key, which points to a sub-array, and `monthly-payment` is its name.

Comment: You could have something like `[6] => Array(name => monthly-values, values => Array(name => test3))` which assigns the `name` monthly-values to the sub-array as a sibling....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange way to do it, but this matches your result as close as possible:

```
$calNames = array(
            'affordability',
            'balloon-payment',
            'budget',
            'early-payoff',
            'fuel-savings',
            'lease-vs-finance',
            array('monthly-payment' => array( 'name' => 'test3' )),
            'refinance',
            'single-pay-lease',
        );
```

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => affordability
    [1] => balloon-payment
    [2] => budget
    [3] => early-payoff
    [4] => fuel-savings
    [5] => lease-vs-finance
    [6] => Array
        (
            [monthly-payment] => Array
                (
                    [name] => test3
                )

        )

    [7] => refinance
    [8] => single-pay-lease
)
```